# WSO2IS NullPointerException when using step authenticator

Tags: saml, wso2-identity-server

Occasionally (?) the WSO2 IS user is unable to authenticate with following exception. When retrying, the user will be authenticated. Any ideas what could be reason / resolution? We set up the session caching.

Using WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0.SP1 / SAML authentication with the authenticator set to advanced (single step, multiple options). I cannot find the correct source code commit to check out (to match the line number in the exception)

Thank you all in advance 
       Gabriel

> TID: [0] [IS] [2016-02-15 13:07:22,914] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
>   -  Exception in Authentication Framework {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:83)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:121)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:94)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:54)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doGet(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:44)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)

**Edit:**

This exception occurs on the WSO2 IS 5.1.0 too

see the [Source code](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/8cd996c1dc6d9e7c0df491322af6e9ddf1cf3709/components/authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authentication/framework/handler/sequence/impl/DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java) line 105

```
StepConfig stepConfig = context.getSequenceConfig().getStepMap().get(currentStep);

// if the current step is completed
if (stepConfig.isCompleted()) {
   stepConfig.setCompleted(false);

ERROR org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Exception in Authentication Framework 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:115)
```

it looks like the stepConfig 'dissapeared' from the authentication config. The setup is done on a single node with session persistence into a database.

Comment: Are there any customization done in this setup? If yes, what are they?

Comment: There's 'Andvanced authenticator' set, where on a single step can the user can choose to authenticate using IWA or a federated SAML IdP.  The environment DB is postgresql migrated from WSO2 IS 5.0.0.SP1 to 5.1.0 (the issue is happening on both versions, after some debug seems the currentStep gets value 2 where there's only a single step defined). Indeed I am unable to reproduce the issue locally, it may dependencies on something I am not aware of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it looks like a problem with concurrency.

When multiple concurrent requests are sent to the SSO endpoint while the user is already authenticated, all threads are attempting to process the request modifying the same authentication context object (currentStep counter) so the cached authentication context comes to an invalid state.

Valid use case is that the client should send only a single request to the SSO endpoint, so the team dealing with the UI have to fix it. But - that's only the a quick fix not preventing the issue in long term. We have to really pick it up with WSO2 (and fix the code ourselves maybe) :)

g.