# WSO2 Identity Server - concurrent authentication requests

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Using the WSO2IS 5.1.0 (and I believe any version will have this issue) we are havving issues with incoming concurrent authentication requests.

The consurrent authentication requests can happend in two cases (as we see that):

First: When the user is not yet authenticated with **multiple posts of the logon form**. This happens when the users are not patient enough and double click the logon button (or spamming the logon submit button, some users do that). Using the custom logon pages we have some control over the UI and we can prevent the user from multiple posts (by disabling the submit button on submit).

Second (this is where we see the real issue): When the user is already authenticated, receiving multiple authentication requests will send the user to the retry.do page with an error message.

```
FINEST|6940/0|Service WSO2IS510|16-10-18 11:05:39|[2016-10-18 11:05:39,295] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Exception in Authentication Framework
FINEST|6940/0|Service WSO2IS510|16-10-18 11:05:39|java.lang.NullPointerException
FINEST|6940/0|Service WSO2IS510|16-10-18 11:05:39|  at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:105)
FINEST|6940/0|Service WSO2IS510|16-10-18 11:05:39|  at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:115)
FINEST|6940/0|Service WSO2IS510|16-10-18 11:05:39|  at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:135)
FINEST|6940/0|Service WSO2IS510|16-10-18 11:05:39|  at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:53)
FINEST|6940/0|Service WSO2IS510|16-10-18 11:05:39|  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
FINEST|6940/0|Service WSO2IS510|16-10-18 11:05:39|  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

This is related to [my older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410919/wso2is-nullpointerexception-when-using-step-authenticator/36640633).

Concurrent auth requests are becomming more common using the HTML5 applications (accessing their services with 401 result will redirect the user with an authentication request). In this case the **processing of the same cached authentication context within multiple threads** will bring the authentication context into an invalid state. Unfortunatelly - the service providers are outside out our control and we're unable to force sending only a single request at the time.

Are there any ways to synchronize / lock the authentication context until processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concurrent user login restriction is not yet supported in WSO2 products. This has been raised as an improvement [1] and may get included in the future.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4191

Comment: Indeed, it is really not a "feature", though this issue is raised due to the misbehaving clients (SP apps).  Until that time we had implemented a custom coordinator with synchronized context (along with sticky session on the load balancer side).